# How can I get the cloned apps in android java using packageManager?

Tags: java, android

I'm working on a new android launcher app and I'm successfully able to retrieve all installed apps using getPackageManager() into a list view.

However, now I'm encountering a problem while testing on some phones which allow to clone you apps, like I can have Whatsapp1 and Whatsapp2(cloned). Now my code does not retrieve the second whatsapp and shows only one.

I have already tried setting different intent flags to my packageManager but it still did not work.

First Method:

```
final PackageManager pm = globalContext.getPackageManager();
List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
```

Second Method:

```
PackageManager manager;
manager = globalContext.getPackageManager();
Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN, null);
i.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_LAUNCHER);
List<ResolveInfo> availableActivities = manager.queryIntentActivities(i, 0);
```

Comment: Anyone who can help with the above scenario?

Comment: any updates....?

Comment: did you find how to do it?

Comment: Yes, using List<UserHandle>. It gives 2 profiles and you will find the cloned apps in the second profile. Basically, called a work profile.  @Racker

Answer (score 0):

No, you cant, because Package Manager only differentiates the apps on the basis of Package name eg: com.whatsapp Both the Whatsapp1 and Whatsapp2 have the same package name.

And I think the clone app feature is purely a Manufacturer thing.

Comment: Thank you for answering! However, I have installed few other launchers and they are able to get the cloned apps.